# Python avoid multiple if statement in assigning and plotting colors based on different conditions

Tags: python

I am assigning different colors for different objects in a dictionary and plotting using pyplot. I used multiple if statements but I wish to avoid doing that. what will be the best way to achieve the plots. Here is my code:

```
for x,y in data.items():
    if x == 'coupe':
        plt.plot(y, ':', color = "yellow")
    if x == 'bike':
        plt.plot(y, ':', color = "black")
    if x == 'truck':
        plt.plot(y, ':', color = "blue")
    if x == 'van':
        plt.plot(y, ':', color = "white")
    if x == 'sedan':
        plt.plot(y, ':', color = "grey")
```

I get my desired result but I just know there would be a better way to achieve this. Thank you

Comment: You need to use a dictionary that maps `x` values to `color` values

Comment: something like associating each color with each key in my original dictionary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all the if statements relate a testing string to an input value to `plt.plot`, we can use a dictionary to store these pairs, and then write the code more neatly:

```
d = {'coupe':'yellow',
     'bike':'black',
     ...}
for x,y in data.items():
    if x in d:
        plt.plot(y, ':', color=d[x])
```

Comment: Which dictionary? I am checking if `x in d` - so we don't get `KeyError`.

Comment: @roganjosh No worries.

Comment: Thank you @ Joe Iddon. I understand it now so what if its more than one condition like color, tire type and transmission? do you associate each key with its multiple values?

Comment: You could have values as tuples of attributes: e.g. `(color, tire type, etc.)`, or have keys as more dictionaries! But I would prefer the former if they are all going to behave identically - why bother storing the meaning of each piece of data - just store them in order. You could then access the color attribute, for instance, with `d[x][0]` and the tire type with `d[x][1]` and so on.